# Access UIScrollViewDelegate from subclass of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm working on a project where I have to work lot of with *UITableViews*. So, I want to detect if the table view (*UIScrollView*) is scrolling.

First I handled it with the *UIScrollViewDelegate* in the *UIViewController* where my *UITableView* is added as a subview. Now, to keep the code clean, I want to subclass *UITableView* and in this class I have to access to the delegate methods of *UIScrollView*, e.g. `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`.

But how can I do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is implement `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` delegate & detect if the scrolling is happening in your `UITableView` or somewhere else.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == self.tableView)
    {
        //your logic here
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: @qPaul this need to be put in which ever `.m` file you have implemented your `UITableView` code.

Answer (score 2):

Those `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods must be defined in a class that is the delegate of the tableview that you want to handle scrolling changes of. If you put these methods in the implementation file of your `UITableView` subclass then you should set the tableview's delegate as itself:

```
[self setDelegate:self];
```

But then you also have to define your `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods in the `UITableView` subclass. This might complicate things if you want to use your `UITableView` subclass more than one place in your project. If I were you, I would double-think about my design and behave accordingly.